# Rails 4 parameters hash not working correctly on update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

When I create a search the correct parameters are coming in fine in the rails 4 params hash via `params[:search]` but on the update action some of my parameters are not working via `params[:search]`. When I looked at the request for the update action I found what I was looking for( code directly below) but when using rails `params` hash I am only getting 4 of them( latter code ). Any ideas on how to fix this?

I am not talking about using the `search_params` function. I am talking about when debugging the app you can make sure the parameters are in the hash. If they are not in the params hash they will not show up no matter what your code looks like in `search_params`

```
"search"=>
  {"gender"=>"2",
   "height_low"=>"60",
   "height_high"=>"70",
   "weight_low"=>"80",
   "weight_high"=>"110",
   "age_low"=>"18",
   "age_high"=>"33",
   "city"=>"fg",
   "province_state"=>"fg",
   "country"=>"CA"}

"search"=>
  {"gender"=>"2", "city"=>"fg", "province_state"=>"fg", "country"=>"CA"}
```

form

```
<%= form_for @search, url: {action: "update"}, html: { method: "post"} do |f| %>
<%= f.label :gender, 'Gender:' %>
<%= f.select(:gender, attractions, :selected => @search.gender) %>
<br />
<%= f.label :height_low, 'Height between:' %>
    <%= f.select(:height_low, heights)  %>
<%= f.select(:height_high, heights) %>
<br />
<%= f.label :weight_low, 'Weight between:' %>
<%= f.select(:weight_low, (80..300).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]})   %>
<%= f.select(:weight_high, (80..300).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}) %>
<br />
<%= f.label :age_low, 'Age between:' %>
<%= f.select(:age_low, (18..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}) %>
<%= f.select(:age_high, (18..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}) %>
<br />
<%= f.label :city, 'City:' %>
<%= f.text_field :city, required: true %>
<%= f.label :province_state, 'Province or State:' %>
<%= f.text_field :province_state, required: true %>
<%= f.label :country, 'Country:' %>
<%= f.country_code_select :country, [[ 'United States', 'US' ], [ 'Canada', 'CA' ]] %>
<div><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
```

search parameters in controller

```
private
def search_params
    params.require(:search).permit(:age_low,:age_high,:weight_low,:weight_high,:height_low,:height_high,:gender,:screen_name,:city,:province_state,:country)
end
```

Comment: Can you include the form that is generating these params?

Comment: I believe update will pass in only params that have been updated. Look at the way the update method works. it doesn't create a new object, but it updates its attributes based on what's passed in. Try modifying some params you aren't seeing now

Comment: I have tried that and they are not being passed in and ones that I have not updated are always still there.

Comment: Can you remove `html: { method: "post"}` and see if that works? Rails will automatically figure out the form method for you based on the object.

Comment: Already ahead of you. removed that and changed route to patch and it still is not working.

Comment: And you're sure that you're not hitting some other form? Check your edit view.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you don't have an `<% end %>` for your form.

Comment: Positive. Just checked it again. I do have an `<% end %>`. I just missed it when I was copying and pasting. What is weird is this worked at one point and then I remember checking it a couple days after I last worked on it and it was not working.

Comment: Maybe do a git-diff and see what changed?

Comment: good idea. I'll check it out though it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much to go on since there isn't any background information to how you are using this has. You might only be permitting specific values in your parameter hash? For example

```
def search_params
  params.require(:search).permit(:gender, :city, :province_state, :country)
end
```

Maybe provide a little more information.